# Python type hint of type "any type"?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to provide a type hint that is any **type**.

For example the type can be `int`, `float`, `str`, or even a yet-to-be-created custom type. It is being used in a case where I am created custom types, and I'll be creating more.

So I need something like:

```py
def myfunc(entry: Union[str, float, char, MyCustomType1, MyCustomType2, ...]) -> Bool:
```

where `entry` can be anything as long as it is a *type*.  To be clear, I am not saying it can be *anything*.  E.g. `entry` can be `int`, but it cannot be `7`.

It is not clear to me what I can provide in the type hint to represent a `Union` of any type, including types not yet defined in the module (to allow for the library to grow, and break nothing).

Comment: `Union[str, float]` (leaving out the undefined others) would allow instances (`"7"`, `7.0`) but **not** types (`myfunc(str)` -> `Argument 1 to "myfunc" has incompatible type "type[str]"; expected "str | float"  [arg-type]`). `Any` would allow instances **and** their types (cc @Matiiss). If you want types, why not... `type` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-type-of-class-objects)?

Comment: @Matiiss No, this would allow literally anything to be passed for `entry`. OP actually very clearly stated that only **types** should be allowed as argument. The real solution is `type[Any]` or simply `type`.

Comment: Yes, by passing `type[Any]`, I was able to solve it.  If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.